# jQuery UI autocomplete drop down list not styled correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've got a autocomplete input on a form but the drop down list is not being styled correctly, it appears like a normal bulleted list of hyperlinks.

This is the rendered hidden list that the autocomplete creates:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: none; top: 253px; left: 20px; width: 162px;">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a id="ui-id-10" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Austria</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a id="ui-id-11" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Australia</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a id="ui-id-12" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Aust-Timor</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a id="ui-id-13" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Austur-Kongo</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

So it looks like its got all the right style classes but if I look at the CSS in Chrome some of the classes are not be applied - namely **ui-menu**

```
element.style {
display: none;
top: 253px;
left: 20px;
width: 162px;
}
Matched CSS Rules
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-br {
border-bottom-right-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
}
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-bl {
border-bottom-left-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
}
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-tr {
border-top-right-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
}
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-tl {
border-top-left-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
}
.ui-widget-content {
border: 1px solid #aaaaaa/*{borderColorContent}*/;
background: #ffffff/*{bgColorContent}*/ url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png)/*{bgImgUrlContent}*/ 50%/*{bgContentXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgContentYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgContentRepeat}*/;
color: #222222/*{fcContent}*/;
}
.ui-widget {
font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif/*{ffDefault}*/;
font-size: 1.1em/*{fsDefault}*/;
}
.ui-autocomplete {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
cursor: default;
}
.ui-front {
z-index: 100;
}
user agent stylesheetul, menu, dir {
display: block;
list-style-type: disc;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
-webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
Inherited from body
body {
color: #333;
font-size: .85em;
font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
```

How can I find out why some style classes are not being applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the JQuery UI javascript, and then setup the AutoComplete functionality?

On my site, the following jQuery javascript needs to be added to the bottom of the page where the autocomplete field is placed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input[data-autocomplete]").each(function() { 
        $(this).autocomplete({ source: $(this).attr("data-autocomplete") });
    });
});
```

Also ensure this code is executed after the load of the JQuery and JQuery UI JS files.

Nick

Comment: Yes, the autocomplete was working correctly, just the style on the drop down wasn't working. Found out that it was because I was missing a stylesheet include for jquery.ui.menu.css. Once that was added all working.